# Jquery Vegas Plugin overlay not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the plugin off of http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/slideshow/

The backgrounds are changing fine, but the overlay image is not working or rendering.

Here is my code I have in the head of the page:

```
<script>
$.vegas('slideshow', {
    backgrounds:
    [
        { src:'/../../images/backdrop.png' },
        { src:'/../../images/backdrop_yellow_trees.png' },
        { src:'/../../images/backdrop.png' }
    ]
})('overlay', {
    src:'/../../assets/vegas/overlays/13.png'
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Pawel There are no errors in the console when viewing in Firefox using firebug

Comment: run it in:
$( document ).ready(function() {
...
});

Comment: @Pawel ah, that was it, simple mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, but based on the @pawel reply over I came to this

```
  $(function() {
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
      backgrounds:[
      { src:'images/pic1.jpg', fade:800 },
      { src:'images/pic2.jpg', fade:800 },
      { src:'images/pic3.jpg', fade:800 },
      { src:'images/pic4.jpg', fade:800 }
      ]
    })('overlay', {
      src:'vegas/overlays/15.png'
    });
  });
```

We probably made the same mistake, just copy paste from the documentation...