# Unable to get Vegas jQuery plugin to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was looking forward to using the Vegas jQuery Plugin for adding slideshows to DOM elements. I wrote some simple code to test it out but it just doesn't seem to run. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I've tried out several variations and even had a look at one existing answer on the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272888/jquery-vegas-plugin-overlay-not-working) but doesn't seem to work either.

```js
    $(function() {
        $.vegas('body', {
          backgrounds:[
          { src:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg'},
          { src:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg'}
          ]
        })
      });
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.2.0/vegas.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Hello world </h1>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.2.0/vegas.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to call "vegas" on a jQuery selected item, so your code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
  console.log($.fn.vegas)
  $('body').vegas({
    slides:[
      {src:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg'},
      {src:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg'}
    ]
  })
});
```

just as the website explains: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/setup/

Comment: What exactly was I missing? ' $(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: Nop, you must call vegas on $("body") instead of passing the "body" as a parameter, and also you have to specify the images as slides instead of backgrounds.

Comment: I shall try this on the originally intended code and get back to you. Will accept the answer then :)